# Apache Drill GROUP BY error

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, apache-drill

I'm trying to query a distributed system.

I have a Postgres instance and a MongoDB instance, both integrated with Apache Drill.

- `cast_info` collection is on MongoDB.
- `title table` is on Postgres.

When I try to launch:

```
SELECT ci.person_id, count(t.title)
FROM mongo.imdb.cast_info as ci 
JOIN postgres.public.title as t 
ON ci.movie_id = t.id 
WHERE t.kind_id = 1
GROUP BY ci.person_id
LIMIT 10;
```

I got this error:

> org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR:
>   IllegalStateException: Already had POJO for id (java.lang.Integer)
>   [com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerator$IdKey@3372bbe8]
>   Fragment 3:0 [Error Id: 69f02c9a-b8b0-444b-9077-fd3cc1799750 on
>   192.168.0.10:31010]

It seems like that the problem is related to GROUP BY clause, since if I delete the GROUP BY (and count) line the query successfully runs.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an outstanding patch for this bug, should be merged soon. Once it is merged you can either build Drill yourself or wait for the 1.5 release.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-4277

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will!